# Blazor Web Assembly Hosted - Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"

Tags: c#, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

Having upgraded from 3.1 to 5.0, I cannot seem to get past this `HttpRequestException` error when trying to fetch data from protected api controllers (those not marked `[Authorize]` are fine).

Although the client app tells me I am authenticated (I have 'hello, user@example.com' up top right for example), I can't seem to be get authenticated with the server. User.Identity just looks like this for example:

[image]

I have a few typed HttpClients, the authenticating one looking like so

```
    public class ApplicationClient
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public ApplicationClient(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<Applicant> GetApplicant() => await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Applicant>("applicant");
}}
```

With `ApplicationClient` being register in `Programme.cs` on `client` side as:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

            builder.Services.AddHttpClient<ApplicationClient>(client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
            
            // Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
            builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("Jcc.ServerAPI"));
            builder.Services.AddScoped<ApplicationState>();
            builder.Services.AddBlazoredModal();
            builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
```

And finally a controller,

```
[Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    public class MyController
    {
        public MyController(...) : base(...)
        {
            ...
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Applicant>> GetCurrentApplicant()
        {
            ...
        }
```

In `Startup.cs` on `Server` app (having chopped and changed and tried about every combination of the below plus others) the pertinent bits of `ConfigureServices()` are:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<JccContext>(options =>
                options.UseNpgsql(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbContext")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
                {
                    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, DbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
                options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
                                           ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto |
                                           ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedHost;
                options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
                options.KnownProxies.Clear();
            });
```

while `Configure()` goes:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseForwardedHeaders();


            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();


            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
```

I just don't what's changed since it worked previously. Identity Server seems to generate the token fine:

[image]

but I keep seeing this:

[image]

[image]

It would be nice to not have to revert back to 3.1 :)

I did try

```
services.AddIdentityServer(opt =>
                        opt.IssuerUri = "https://localhost:5001"
                        )
```

As per a post a few years back but no dice and I think it was a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you regenerate the signing keys, then the keys in tokens already issued will be invalidated. For production you need to make sure the signing keys is persisted.

you can look at the kid claim in the JWT header of your tokens. It must be found in the /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks.

Be aware that API's and clients cache the downloaded keys for 24 hours by default.

In production you need to use this method to add the signing key that you want to sign your tokens with

```
AddSigningCredential
```

See the documentation [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/startup.html?highlight=AddSigningCredential#key-material)

In production you should not use this method **AddDeveloperSigningCredential**.

Comment: Thank you, although what do you suggest I change? I've been wrestling with this for about a week so the 24 hours cache is probably not an issue :)

Comment: Ah, actually I do only use the developer signing credential in development, I just shortened the environment conditionals for the sake of brevity. It was actually in development that I was having the problem, although, bizarrely, removing the call to AddDeveloperSigningCredential() seems to have solved this for now. Did they change something?!

Comment: You should either use AddDeveloperSigningCredential or AddSigningCredential in development. Do you use version 4 or version 5? perhaps you regenerate the key each time you start locally?

Comment: In the output, 'Starting IdentityServer4 version 4.1.0'. Using dotnet 5.0. It kinda feels strange that it's working without AddDeveloperSigningCredential() but if it works, what the heck :P

Comment: not using AddDeveloperSigningCredential and not using AddSigningCredential sounds wierd, perhaps its added somewhere else? do you get a key in the JWKS endpoint?

Comment: {"keys":[{"kty":"RSA","use":"sig","kid":"Development","e":"AQAB","n":"1xR_6tYj_maOndf_YmCHOJzcJaDUBA4-4s5n1e7teeFX0G8ngLhqChC0-IDA0erwtutZyjYB8u0qOKavlZUqjFclz6rWfBXkUYH6NaaBd-7oJ4eGpieTXzwQNHXxPTREzOHGufHU99sYbuwuJWbxRslBXX6Emw8vAMt1KKYgpG_2RvcBASe0t4cxxO_pd7gllFbWdk1LfztyeG9Y3gvcc2UrF_Z_IHmzTXH1Ek_DZ0_uAalql80nYPhCHuJnrFVjELhW8a37PsjEOip29ys0njwRS1hBoksOJ8I3XisUOPEiBQtVMZGCTdc6TFLH7sLpj1uk8WL-5MlDJfRNokmAqQ","alg":"RS256"}]}

Comment: the kid='Development' must also exist in the tokens for for them to be able to validate the signature of the tokens

Comment: Maybe this is handled in development by default now?! I don't recall seeing the call to AddDeveloperSigningCredential() in the latest [Blazor docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) tbf - I just had it remaining from 3.1. I'll tinker around some more - hopefully it holds up! :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: AddDeveloperSigningCredential you use in identityServer and you don't put identtiyserver in blazor?  correct? bit confused here :-)